# Horse taming bug

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was in this new survival world and I just found a saddle. I've read that you have to right-click on the horse to ride them, and continue doing so until they don't throw you off anymore and hearts appear on top of them. Weirdly enough, when I right-click on them they just immediately do this

[image: screenshot]

Instead of showing me that I've mounted it.

I've right-clicked the horse multiple times and it still does that. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had you made sure that you were using an empty hand on the horse?

Horse taming interactions don't really work unless you have nothing in your hands.

Comment: Wow! That one trick works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that I could help out